# No module and Modernizr error when adding angular to requirejs

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, requirejs, angular-ui-bootstrap, modernizr

Im trying to add AngularJS to my web application which already makes use of RequireJS. When loading my test page, i am seeing:

```
1) Error: No module: MyApp
      ...),factory:a("$provide","factory"),service:a("$provide","service"),value:a("$prov...

2) TypeError: Modernizr is undefined
if (!Modernizr.history) {
```

**I am using AngularJS v1.1.5**

Here's my tree:

```
resources
   - CSS
   - js
        - controllers
             - MainController.js
        - libs
             - angular.js
             - jquery.js
             - require.js
             - mondernizr.js
             ......
             ......
             ......
        main.js
        mainApp.js
pages
        test.html
```

**main.js**

```
(function(require) {
'use strict';

require.config({
    baseUrl: '/resources/js',
    paths: {
        'zepto'     : 'libs/zepto',
        'jquery'    : 'libs/jquery',
        'angular'   : 'libs/angular',
        'router'    : 'libs/page',
        'history'   : 'libs/history.iegte8',
        'event'     : 'libs/eventemitter2'
    },
    shim: {
        'zepto'     : { exports: '$' },
        'angular'   : { exports : 'angular' },
        'router'    : { exports: 'page'},
        'modernizr' : { exports: 'Modernizr' }
    }
});

require([ 'jquery', 'angular', 'routes', 'modernizr', 'event' ], function($, angular, routes, Modernizr, Event) {
    function bootstrap() {
        var app = new Event(),
            router = routes(app);

        if (typeof console !== 'undefined') console.info('>> module routes loaded ... executing router');
        router({ click: false, popstate: false });
        if (typeof console !== 'undefined') console.info('>> executed router');
    }

    $(function() {
        if (!Modernizr.history) {
            require([ 'history' ], bootstrap);
            require([ 'controllers/MainController' ], bootstrap);
        } else {
            require([ 'controllers/MainController' ], bootstrap);
            bootstrap();
        }
    });
});


})(this.require);
```

**mainApp.js**

```
define(['angular'], function(angular) {
return angular.module('MyApp', []);
})
```

**MainController.js**

```
require(['mainApp'], function(mainApp) {
mainApp.controller('MainController', function($scope) {
    $scope.data = {message: "Hello"};
})
});
```

**test.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="MyApp">
<head>
<script src="/assets/js/vendor/require.js" data-main="/assets/js/main"></script>
</head>
<body>
       <div ng-controller="MainController">
    {{ data.message + " world" }}
       </div>   

</body>
</html>
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The `No module: MyApp` problem is causes by the Angular automatic initialization: `<html ng-app="MyApp">`. Angular loads *before* mainApp.js, sees the `ng-app` and tries to find a module which is not (yet) there.

The solution is to manually bootstrap Angular from within main.js and inside the document load event, as described [here](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.16/docs/guide/bootstrap).

I am not sure about the problem with Modernizr; I *guess* you are *NOT* loading it at all.  RequireJs is not complaining because of the `shim`. How are you loading it? It is not included in your `paths` configuration. You may want to load Modernizr as independent script before all other scripts (as per recommendations), in which case no `paths` configuration is needed and the `shim` is enough.